# Iphone memory leak issue?

Tags: iphone, instruments

The memory is leaking in this code fragment, how to fix this memory leak ?

```
-(NSDictionary *)sanitizedFinancialLine:(NSDictionary *)theFinancialLine
{
 NSMutableDictionary *aFinancialLine = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:theFinancialLine];


for (id key in [aFinancialLine allKeys]) {
 id something = [aFinancialLine objectForKey:key];
 if ([something respondsToSelector:@selector(decimalValue)]) {
something = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:[(NSNumber *)something decimalValue]]; // memory is leaking here
[aFinancialLine setObject:something forKey:key];
   }
}
 return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:aFinancialLine];// and here
}
```

Comment: It would be good for you to paste in the text of your code instead of taking a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

As written, there isn't a leak *in that code*.

What may be happening, though, is the `NSDecimalNumber` *allocated* on that line of code is being leaked because it is being over-retained (or under-released) somewhere else.  Try build-and-analyze and/or turn on 'track retain events' in the allocations instrument.

Note that you could just return `aFinancialLine` without creating an `NSDictionary` instance (doesn't hurt to do so, though, and it is more defensive).